# Demos for Pytorch and IOS are not working on MacBook M1

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to learn how to use Pytorch in IOS devices. https://github.com/pytorch/ios-demo-app/tree/master/ImageSegmentation

After downloading the file `deeplabv3_scripted.pt` I run `python deeplabv3.py` to generate the `ptl` file.

Unfortunately that does not work, I get the error:

```
File "/Users/name/opt/miniconda3/envs/ios_pytorch/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: rate limit exceeded
```

I have also tried
https://github.com/pytorch/ios-demo-app/tree/master/HelloWorld

but then `mobile_net_v2` does not exist in models.

I am using the latest pytorch and Python 3.9 and Mac Silicon M1.

Python 3.7 does not work either.

Comment: Happening in Colab also....

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is getting this error:"HTTP Error 403: rate limit exceeded", then you can take your model from a different way,

```
import torchvision
model = torchvision.models.resnext50_32x4d(pretrained=True)
```

it should work!